# Collect this month data from SQL using PHP

Tags: php, sql

How can I get data from SQL using PHP of this month (not last 30 days).
If this is January 10, I wan to collect data from January 1 to January 10.

I tried the following code, but it seems to be taking data from last month also!

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(earnings) 
        FROM tablename 
        WHERE username='$membername' 
        AND date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)";
```

in database date in saved in following format `2020-12-26 10:02:41`

Comment: You are still writing scripts that are open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// set TimeZone, Local or UTC (can make a difference for edge cases)
$month = date('m');
$year = date('Y');
$sql = "SELECT SUM(earnings) FROM tablename
        WHERE username='$membername' AND MONTH(date) = $month
        AND YEAR(date) = $year";
```

Comment: I have no idea why this answer is upvoted and accepted.  It does not do what the question clearly asks for.  `If this is January 10, I wan to collect data from January 1 to January 10.`  Perhaps it is relying on business logic that `earnings` will not be stored with future dates, but this will be misleading to future researchers who may have future-stored values.  This answer is also missing its educational explanation.

Comment: @mickmackusa The OP asked for data from *"this month (not last 30 days)".* By *"this month"* I presume he means the *current calendar month,* and that "January 1 to January 10" is only an example for a "current date" of January 10. If the current date is February 25, this answer will return data from February 1 to February 25. I can not say whether this solution correctly solves the OP's business logic; only that it correctly answers the question.

Comment: Furthermore, there is no need to pass php date-related variables into the sql when sql is perfectly capable of generating these values.  Because the username variable is required in the sql, a prepared statement with a bound parameter is called for.

Comment: True enough, but php is easier and allows easier control of the desired timezone. SQL injection is a strong topic on its own and certainly worth mentioning, but not part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'SELECT SUM(earnings)  FROM tablename WHERE username="$membername" and date LIKE 
 CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),"-", MONTH(CURDATE()),"-%")'
```

Comment: While this code may help with the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.

Comment: Using `LIKE` on date-type columns is not considered best practice and probably performs worse than comparisons against dedicated date functions.  A prepared statement is called for, as well.